# ASP.NET MVC 3 – How can I route directly to an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller called HomeController with the actions Index(), MethodOne() and MethodTwo(). Each of these just return View() for now.
When I create an action link with the code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
```

I get the hyperlink:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

This is good however using the same ActionLink extention method to route too MethodOne I get the hyperlink:

```
<a href="/Home/MethodOne">MethodOne</a></li>
```

What do I need to configure so my site will accept the hyperlink “/MethodOne”, this currently returns a 404.
I have a suspicion this may be related to routing. My routing table is currently the default:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a route like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MethodOne", //Your route name.
    "methodone", //What your browser/user will see at the URL bar: localhost.com/methodone 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "MethodOne" } //What MVC3 will route to.
);
```

That will map and catch the request to the `Home/MethodOne` action method.

Comment: Spot-on, thanks. I had some trouble with the order of precedence with my routes. Putting the default route to the bottom of the list alleviated that. Might be useful in your answer.